# How to get the records where the term data is not in the presiding effective date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table test_member with below data.

```
meme_ck mepe_eff_dt             mepe_term_dt
1       6/1/2010 12:00:00 AM    12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM
1       5/1/2010 12:00:00 AM    6/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
1       3/1/2010 12:00:00 AM    4/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
1       5/1/2010 12:00:00 AM    6/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
1       2/1/2010 12:00:00 AM    3/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
1       1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM    2/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
2       2/10/2010 12:00:00 AM   3/10/2010 12:00:00 AM
2       1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM   2/10/2010 12:00:00 AM
2       6/10/2010 12:00:00 AM   12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM
2       5/10/2010 12:00:00 AM   6/10/2010 12:00:00 AM
2       3/10/2010 12:00:00 AM   4/10/2010 12:00:00 AM
3       1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM    12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM
3       10/1/2010 12:00:00 AM   11/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
3       11/1/2010 12:00:00 AM   12/1/2010 12:00:00 AM.
```

For every `meme_ck` the `mepe_term_dt` will be the next `meme_ck` 
`mepe_eff_dt`, but there are few `meme_ck` with `mepe_eff_dt` that doesn't have the earlier `mepe_term_dt` and i need to figure out those records with sql query , expertise please help!!!!!!

Comment: What version of SQL? And are `mepe_eff_dt` and `mepe_term_dt` date-ish datatypes, or are they string representation of a date?  Also, `9999` is not a valid year. What does that represent?

Comment: How about expected results? I think it's the best explanation.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @Shawn I think 9999 is just a way to represent "current" or "most-up-to-date" information.

Comment: You seem to be trying to identify the records that have the `12/31/9999` "date", but what you seem to be asking for would also include gaps in some of your data points. Are those also supposed to be included?

Comment: @YilunZhang I understand what it's supposed to "represent", but if that is actual data in the table, that could indicate some fundamental problems.

Comment: The format of your data **implies** you're storing these dates as a `varchar`. *I hope you're not.*

Comment: @Shawn Good point. But regardless the format of the data, it doesn't need to be datetime to solve this specific question.

Comment: @YilunZhang Only if you're doing some type-casting to get actual date objects to work with. But if it's `varchar` strings, then how do you order `1/1/2011` and `10/1/2010`? And then you'd also have to do some checking for `12/31/9999` to change it to a `NULL`-type value. When working with dates, strings make it a pain to do any good analysis, especially when performance is a concern.

Comment: @Shawn For this problem, if you look at the given data, it's all beginning of month. That means if there's any gap, that beginning of month date will only show up once, so you can just count the occurrence and get those with count 1, and remove year 9999 and the earliest date.

Comment: Its not the original data, i mocked it for an example purpose. here is the thing, i need to figure out the record with date that doesn't have the preceding term date as the effective date, for example for meme_ck =1 the term_date with 04/01.2010 should be the effective date for the next record of meme_ck =1 but it has the next record as 5/01/2010 as effective data , so i need to figure out all the meme_ck with such dates which doesn't have the earlier term date as the next record effective date.. i was thinking of using over(partition by) but still it doesn't work

Comment: I try to look at these as more a "Can you help solve my problem?" than a "How do I get this specific answer?". That seems like an awful lot of hard text processing to come to a solution that would be pretty efficient with proper date types. And still with text "dates" that should be able to be accomplished with an ANTI-JOIN.

Comment: Yes as Zhang mentioned the 12/31/9999 is the present active  date for the record once it get its term date that will be updated and 12/31/9999 will go tot he next recod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

In the comments it was clarified that the OP was looking for records that had a starting date with a gap in front of it, rather than after it. This can still be accomplished with the anti-join, just going the other way on the `JOIN`.

```
SELECT t1.meme_ck, t1.mepe_eff_dt, t1.mepe_term_dt
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 t2 ON t1.meme_ck = t2.meme_ck 
    AND t1.mepe_eff_dt = t2.mepe_term_dt
WHERE t2.meme_ck IS NULL

ORDER BY t1.meme_ck, t1.mepe_eff_dt, t1.mepe_term_dt
```

This also includes the first records for a `meme_ck`, since by definition they won't have an ending date before their starting date. This will also include the final date if there is a gap before it.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=24166fd317b911b27a8582c099126972

Demonstrates the difference between using date values from strings vs actually using date objects. Because of the data, valid rows are returned, but you can see in the ordering that a string "date" in that format may sort in a different order. When working with things that are supposed to represent dates, I've always found it *MUCH* better to work with actual dates.  *( NOTE: I also changed the format of the date when I made them SQL date types, because dbfiddle.uk uses DD-MM-YYYY instead of the MM-DD-YYYY style common in the US. So again, you can see how SQL can represent a date different than a string. Also note that as an actual date, it converted an empty string into an epoch date of 1900-01-01. )*

=======================================================

**ORIGINAL:**
This problem can be solved with an anti-join, that should take care of whether the "dates" are real date datatypes or if they are varchars.

```
SELECT t1.meme_ck, t1.mepe_eff_dt, t1.mepe_term_dt 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t2 ON t1.meme_ck = t2.meme_ck 
    AND t1.mepe_term_dt = t2.mepe_eff_dt
WHERE t2.meme_ck IS NULL
    AND t1.mepe_term_dt <> '12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM' 
        /* Or whatever your ending date is. */
ORDER BY t1.meme_ck, t1.mepe_eff_dt, t1.mepe_term_dt
```

The `ORDER BY` isn't really necessary. I just included it for illustration purposes.

```
 meme_ck | mepe_eff_dt           | mepe_term_dt         
 ------: | :-------------------- | :--------------------
       1 | 3/1/2010 12:00:00 AM  | 4/1/2010 12:00:00 AM 
       2 | 3/10/2010 12:00:00 AM | 4/10/2010 12:00:00 AM
       3 | 11/1/2010 12:00:00 AM | 12/1/2010 12:00:00 AM
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9b27da9988bc60a56ae86c9f093d3346

Comment: Thanks You so much  shawn.

Comment: @gowtami Are you looking for rows with a `mepe_eff_dt` that don't match up with the previous `mepe_term_dt`, or are you looking for rows with a `mepe_term_dt` that ends before the next `mepe_eff_dt`? Can you provide an example of the rows you think should be returned?

Comment: @shawn--looking for rows with a mepe_eff_dt that don't match up with the previous mepe_term_dt.

Comment: @gowtami So just to verify, which rows in your example do you want returned?

Comment: @gowtami And to you also want the earliest record, since it won't have a previous term date?

Comment: @gowtami Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Shawn , i am expecting the meme_ck  with effective date '5/1/2010 should be returning,a s these is the record should have the earlier term date of 4/1/2010 as the next effective date

Comment: You should also get `meme_ck` for 2 on `5/10/2010`, since there's a gap with the previous `mepe_term_dt`. This also gets the first records in the set since those won't have a previous date. They can be excluded if you don't want them returned. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=00fce47affd99d1eed333388a905976b  That fiddle also shows the sorting difference between text "dates" and actual date objects.